# Serialize a Parsed Lambda Expression to Database

Tags: c#, dynamic, expression

I have users who will generate business rules via simple statements that result in true or false
Example:  Result > 10 AND Result < 100

I am using Linq.Dynamic to convert these statements  I am finding the ParseLambda is taking too long (simple example took 21ms).  So I would like to save the Lambda Expression to the database to pull and use later.  From my testing I have found the call to ParseLambda is taking the most time, therefore I am wondering if it is possible to serialize this Lambda Expression and persist to a database pulling it when needed.  The idea is to have it saved to the database already parsed.

Maybe this is the wrong approach all together.  I thought about using CodeDom and scripting but found I would have to create an assembly for every rule, which would pollute the AppDomain, I could have over 1000 rules.

I am open to other options, maybe there is a better library out there.

```
ParameterExpression P = Expression.Parameter(typeof(InternalEvalData), _ParameterHeading);
LambdaExpression X = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { P }, null, parsedExpression);
result = (bool)d.DynamicInvoke(testData);
```